# Creating LineString from CSV with lat/lon coordinates of beginning and ending points

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, linestring, polyline-creation

I am iterating through a CSV file of tornadoes, and for each row getting the beginning lat, beginning long, ending lat, and ending long. And I am trying to plot their line geometry on a map.

I got the points for the starting points but I am having trouble creating the lines to show the path of the tornadoes.

I have:

```py
for i, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    lx = row[begin_long],[ending_long]
    ly = row[begin_lat],[ending_lat]
    line_geometry.append(LineString(lx,ly))
```

Comment: The LineString expects something like `LineString([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])`, while now you pass ((x1, x2), (y1, y2))

Answer (score 1):

The `LineString` object is initalised with a list of coordinate pairs, e.g.

```
line = LineString([(0, 1), (2, 3)])
```

It looks like your coordinates are in a DataFrame. In that case you can use the DataFrame.apply method to create a linestring:

```
df = DataFrame([[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]], columns=["x0", "x1", "y0", "y1"])

def make_line(row):
    coordinates = [(row["x0"], row["y0"]), (row["x1"], row["y1"])]
    return LineString(coordinates)

df["line"] = df.apply(make_line, axis=1)
```